# Running a repetitive task in Node.js for each row in a postgres table on a different interval for each row

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, knex.js

What would be a good approach to running a repetitive task for each row in a large postgres db table on a different per row interval in Node.js.

**To give you some more context, here's a quick description of the application:**

- It's a chat based customer support app.
- It consists of teams, which can be either a client team or a support team. Teams have users, which can be either client users or support users.
- Client users send messages to a support team and wait for one of that team's users to answer their question.
- When there's an unanswered client message waiting for a response, every agent for the receiving support team will receive a notification every n seconds (n being set on a per-team basis by the team admin).

**So this task needs to infinitely loop through the rows in the teams table and send notifications if:**

1. The team has messages waiting to be answered.
2. N seconds have passed since the last notification was sent (N being the number of seconds set by the team admin).

   - There might be a better approach to this condition altogether.

**So my questions are:**

1. What is an efficient way to infinitely loop through a postgres table with no upper limit on the number rows?

   - Should I load 1 row at a time? Several at a time?
2. What would be a good way to do this in Node?

   - I'm using Knex. Does Knex provide a mechanism for lazy loading a table and iterating through the rows?

Answer (score 2):

A) **Running a repetitive task** via node can be done via a the js built-in function '[setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)'.

```
// run the intervalFnc() every 5 seconds
const timerId = setTimeout(intervalFnc, 5000);

function intervalFnc() { console.log("Hello"); }

// to quit running it:
clearTimeout(timerId);
```

Then your interval function can do the actual work. An alternative would be to use cron (linux), or some OS process scheduler to trigger the function. I would use this method if you want to do it every minute, and a cron job if you want to do it every hour (in between these times becomes more debatable).

B) **An efficient way...**

B-1) Retrieving a block of records from a DB will be more efficient than one at a time. Knex has [.offset](https://knexjs.org/#Builder-offset) and [.limit](https://knexjs.org/#Builder-limit) clauses to choose a group of records to retrieve. A sample from the knex doc:

```
knex.select('*').from('users').limit(10).offset(30)
```

B-2) Database indexed access is important for performance if your tables are very large. I would recommend including an status flag field in your table to note which records are 'in-process', and also include a "next-review-timestamp" field with both fields being both indexed. Retrieve the records that have `status_flag='in-process' AND next_review_timestamp <= now()`. Sample:

```
knex('users').where('status_flag', 'in-process').whereRaw('next_review_timestamp <= now()')
```

Hope this helps!